# RPi freezes at booting. Log screen attached

Tags: pi-3, boot, raspbian-stretch, troubleshooting

I'm working on a project where I have a couple of RPis recording some audio. Recently the devices stopped working and after probing I found out that devices stops at following screen while booting, and it needs input from keyboard to proceed with booting and it boots fine after pressing return.

[image]

Since devices are headless, there is no way to no if it needs an input. My question is : has anyone faced the similar problem ? If yes, what helped them to solve it ?

Here is some info on the systems.

RPi model : 3 B+ | 
SD Card : San Disk 128 GiB |
OS : Raspbian Stretch, Release 2.3 - March 2018 |

Additional info : The nature of project is such that RPi could be writing audio files to disk while devices could be switched off abruptly. Could that be the cause of broken file system and hence this message ?

Following is the screenshot of `journalctl -xb` entries.

[image]

Comment: looks like (at least) the boot partition on the sd card (assuming you're not booting from USB) is faulty - can you read that partition in a different computer?

Comment: @JaromandaX: I'm booting from an SD card. I do have 10 SD cards with the same fault. I tried to read (even did fsck) boot partition on mac and I was able to read it perfectly and when I tried to boot it up, I got the same error. I'm not sure if serial1 timeout has anything to do with it. (see 2nd snapshot logs).

Comment: nah, I get the same serial1 timeout - 10 sdcards with the same fault? or 1 raspberry pi with one fault? seems like the latter

Comment: @JaromandaX: 10 different devices with the same issue. It can't be a coincidence. There must be something causing it.

Comment: well, yeah - that's why I said it's more likely a faulty pi? (I'm assuming you get the behaviour on every boot?)

Comment: @JaromandaX: It usually clears up when I reboot it again but on headless systems, there is no way to know if system needs a reboot.

Comment: @JaromandaX: I ended up creating `rootfs` and `boot` read only with a separate partition for data to write. It seems to be working okay. Thanks for your comments though.